# Angular application hosted on Hostinger cannot perform HTTP request, and also returns error 404 when accessing routes

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, hosting

I have an Angular application hosted on the Hostinger platform. I can access the home screen on my computer and navigate to other routes using the routing service. However, if I type the route in the url it returns 404, and I also cannot make HTTP requests using Angular on the Hostinger platform, the request simply does not work, and locally and on AWS servers it works.

What could I do to resolve this issue? I don't know what to do anymore, there aren't many resources about it on the internet

Comment: Just like any SPA you need to configure your server to redirect all requests to index.html. so you'll have to find out how to do that for your host provider.